# need to upgrade from AND, OR filters on elasticsearch to boolean queries for ES7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, booleanquery

i'm trying to update a query that was possible on ElasticSearch 2 and does not exist in ES7.
it's this query below:

```
{
"filter":
  {
  "and":[
     {
      "or":[
        { 
         "range":
          {
           "date_of_birth":
             {
             "lte": 5
             }
           }
         },
          {
           "range":
              {
              "age":{
                   "gte": 15
                    }
              }
            }]
       },{
         "range":
          {
            "begin_time":
              {
               "lte": 23
              }
           }
        }]
    } 
}
```

i am aware that i should use boolean queries but because it is a filter, i am confused and i would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, just replace `and` by `bool/filter` and `or` by `bool/should`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "date_of_birth": {
                    "lte": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "age": {
                    "gte": 15
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "begin_time": {
              "lte": 23
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val, i get it! 
But does these queries have an effect on the scoring ?

Comment: If you want scoring to kick in, then you need to replace `filter` by `must`, otherwise you can keep `filter`. But since you're not doing any full-text search, your constraints are just basically yes/no constraints and not "how well does my document match".

Comment: exactly what i needed to understand, Thanks for your quick reply :)